# Title update directly from the WP7app

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, push, tile

My problem is:
I would like to allow my user to pin single element information from the WP7app (like information from listbox item) to the Live tile. How to do that? TileScheduler only updates image and push notification needs exclusive webservice to handle them. I would like allow my app to set the tile value.

Please, help.

xawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have control of the image used. You can add text to an image using [WriteableBitmap.Render()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

If you're ok with waiting one hour for the first TileScheduler update to take place you can do this locally, however if you want a more responsive result you will, as you noted, need to implement a web service and the PNS.